# Nexus загружает артифакт, но я получаю ошибку, что артифакт нельзя найти в maven-public

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, nexus

У меня есть своя библиотека service.jar которую я подключаю через nexus. Я залил ее в maven-releases. Все настройки выполнил согласно официальной документации nexus: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/maven-repositories

Все работает корректно: библиотека скачивается (заведомо удалил из локального репозитория), доступ к ней есть. Но меня смущает сообщение, которое я получаю при импорте: 
***Could not find artifact myGroupId:myArtifactId:pom:myVersion in nexus (http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-public/)*** (и откуда появился этот "pom" в пути?)

Если зайти в менеджер репозиториев nexus, то там в maven-public моя библиотека есть.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если кто знает, в чем дело.

Comment: не совсем понятно при каких действиях выдается сообщение

Comment: @keekkenen Если в локальном репозитории нет определенной библиотеки, а затем я добавляю зависимость в свой pom и делаю импорт, появляется это сообщение. Если же в локальном репозитории библиотека уже есть, то данного сообщения не появляется

Comment: вероятно, это из-за того, что IDE автоматически не проверяет на изменение зависимостей при редактировании pom файла или она не успела проверить и докачать нужное, а импорт в коде уже добавлен

Comment: @keekkenen это можно как-то исправить?